# Where to place "Change Status" button on a Order page that improves look and feel?

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, buttons, layout

I am looking for general UX advice on how to arrange buttons on the screen, in particular, the "Change Status" button that I'm adding onto the screen below.

There were two buttons (`Accept`, `Reject`) before but now I am adding `Change Status` buton and there isn't a good place to put it.

I am also thinking that instead of "Change Status" I will have a button that says `Put on Hold` and conversely, `Remove Hold`, because that's what will be the functionality behind the button - to place hold on order and remove hold from order.

That functionality does not have to be a button, it could be a select box or a toggle switch but I think a button is most clear.  I am open to suggestions.

**My current Screen Mockup**

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvh7Tb.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Individual Order Line Items do not affect `Order Details` and `Order Comments` - both of which belong to the entire order.

**Update**

Moved all 3 buttons into their own group, and placed them right of `Order Comments`.

Comment: The "order line items" are different items and the "order details" and "order comments" belong to the actually selected one?

Comment: "Order line items" are different individual items that belong to the order.  "Order comments" and "order details" belong to the entire order and do not change regardless of what item is selected

Comment: Do the Reject/Accept buttons need to be inside the "Order details" box?

Comment: No they don't, they can be elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

As the buttons refer to the whole item I would not place them inside a particular element from it (currently Accept/Reject buttons are inside the Order details box). Instead you could place them either "out" or all the buttons under their own box (a "box for actions").

If there is no "Save" button I am not sure a toggle for the Hold status is the best idea. I would expect to trigger an action when clicking those buttons (right now Accept/Reject). But in desktop with a toggle I would expect the action to take place after I click a "Save/Accept/Apply" button. So I would keep it in a button. The idea you propose would still need a label that tells the exact status of the item, to leave no doubt. You could leave the "Change Status" button which toggles the label "The item is on Hold". If you take this approach I don't think there is need to change the button text.

Comment: Now I see I posted a similar answer with you. Sorry, I was focused on the question. I agree with you.

Comment: @MadalinaTaina Ah, no problem :) I was curious for what box were you referring to.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that the "change status" is a main action, for the "order details" box, not for the comments, so the obvious place for this button is in the left box.

You will have for the order the actions: 
- accept/ reject or 
- change status

[image]

Comment: Do you mean in the "Order details" box?

Comment: @Alvaro Thank you for the comment. Yes, for the main box, with the action related to the status: accept, reject or put on hold. Comments seems a secondary section.

Comment: Great visual, I would however only put the Reject a bit closer to Accept (as they fall in the same category).

Answer (score 0):

**Recommendations**

1. Change the button text to be either "Put on hold" or "Remove Hold" based on the orders status.
2. Add a label that says "On Hold" if the orders is on hold, under the comments box.
3. Change the color of the button based on if it says "Put on Hold" or "Remove Hold". Stay away from green or red, but the colors should be different enough to stand out from each other.